# Design patterns NOT in the Gang of Four?

Tags: design-patterns, gang-of-four

We all know the great book about design patterns known as Gang of Four, and the Patterns for Enterprise by Fowler.

I would like to propose this wikified question to collect unusual software patterns for obscure and nice situations, spanning procedural programming, functional programming, OO and AO programming. Give your imagination and experience full freedom.

Somewhat Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337/beyond-gof-design-patterns

Comment: A lot of the GoF patterns are now out-dated, too. Also, some of them were designed to get around the general awfulness of C++, rather than being inherently good ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Portland Pattern Repository](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WelcomeVisitors) already exists as an early repository of patterns and is the original wiki. There's no point reinventing the pattern wiki.

Comment: I think c2.com is not allowing updates any more.